# How to detect an event and call user defined function to edit tick labels on Python matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, matplotlib, event-handling, mouseevent

I am plotting huge data sets (arrays in length of over 5E5), where the x-values are utc timestamps. I want to convert them to format HH:MM:SS instead of e.g. 1.47332886e+09 seconds. Therefore I had made a small function to convert the timestamps. Since the data sets, which I am plotting, are huge, I can not convert all the timestamps to datetime tuples. It would take too long. So I figured that I can read the xtick values and convert only these values to desired format. The Problem is, as I do this, the x-tick labels are fixed and by zooming the x-tick labels they are staying the same. So basically I need to run my function every time I zoom. I would rather automate this. So I tried to use event handling for that, but couldn't find a way to call my function in Event handler.

How can I call my function in event handler correctly? Or is there a better way to achieve my goal?

(I am using Python 3.3)

Here is my code:

```
def timeStamp2dateTime(timeArray):
    import datetime
    import numpy as np
    # first loop definition:
    timeArrayExport = []
    timeArrayExport = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timeArray[0])
    for i in range(1,len(timeArray)):
        # Convert timestamps to datetime
        timeArrayExport = np.append( timeArrayExport, datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timeArray[i]) )
    return(timeArrayExport)


def set_xticklabels_timestamp2time(ax):
    '''
    this function reads xtick values (assuming that they are timestamps) and
    converts the xtick values to datetime format. from datetime format is
    xticklabel list generated in format HH:MM:SS and also added to the plot
    which has the handle "ax" (function input).
    '''
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    # manipulating the x-ticks -----
    plt.pause(0.1) # update the plot
    xticks = ax.get_xticks()
    xticks_dt = timeStamp2dateTime(xticks)
    xlabels = []
    for item in xticks_dt:
        xlabels.append(str(item.hour).zfill(2) +':'+ str(item.minute).zfill(2) +':'+ str(item.second).zfill(2))
    ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels)
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate() # rotates the x-axis values so that it is more clear to read
    plt.pause(0.001) # update the plot
    return(ax)


def onrelease(event):
    ax = set_xticklabels_timestamp2time(ax)


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# example data
x = np.arange(1.47332886e+09,1.47333886e+09) # UTC timestamps
y = np.sin(np.arange(len(x))/1000) + np.cos(np.arange(len(x))/100)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y,'.-')
ax.grid(True)

ax = set_xticklabels_timestamp2time(ax)

# try to automate the xtick label convertion
try:
    cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', set_xticklabels_timestamp2time(ax))
except:
    cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', onrelease)
# => both ways fails
```

Thank you for reading this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a ticklabelformatter.  See [the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter) or [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_ticker1.html).  What it does is to let matplotlib figure out what the ticks should be and every time they change, put the correct label.  In the linked example they use `matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter`, which takes a user defined function

```
def millions(x, pos):
    'The two args are the value (x) and tick position (pos)'
    return '$%1.1fM' % (x*1e-6)
```

simply scaling the input value `x` to millions, and appending it to the string `x_in_millions M`, which is returned as the new tick-label.  This should work with your case too, if you create the function that takes your timestamp in seconds, and transforms it to your preferred formatting and return a string. When the function is defined you set it with the following commands:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
formatter = FuncFormatter(millions)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```